# Present continues and present simple, case verb(look)?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

I hear you're having your house repainted !!!

1. How does it look ?
2. How is it looking ?

Grammar's rule  is :
We use present continues when we want to emphasis the station is temporary.

but the two questions are correct ? I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-How does it look ?
2-How is it looking ?

Both the sentences are grammatical and Fine.

if you are asking about how the house looks at the present time" its appearance" we can use both , without any difference in meaning , However, the use of the presrnt simple is more common than the present continuous. but, many people use the present continuous for emphasis.